# Uncountability of the Set of all Infinite Binary Sequences - Diagonalization

Tags: real-analysis, computational-complexity

One proof of the uncountability of $R$ goes:

Suppose a correspondence $f$ exists between $N$ and $R$ such that:
$f(1)=m_1.x_{11}x_{12}x_{13}x_{14}...$
$f(2)=m_2.x_{21}x_{22}x_{23}x_{24}...$
$f(3)=m_3.x_{31}x_{32}x_{33}x_{34}...$
$\quad \quad . $
$\quad \quad . $
$\quad \quad . $

Construct $x$ such that its $i^{th}$ fractional digit is different than the $i^{th}$ digit of $f(i)$.
Constructed in this $x$ will be different from any $f(i)$
Hence $R$ is uncountable.

The author then states that the proof that the set of all infinite binary sequences is uncountable is similar. Does that mean we just replace the decimal digits with binary digits?

Comment: I don't think the values of f are expressed correctly in the outline of the proof you have.

Comment: @user137481 I am unclear about what you mean. Please feel free to edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: @user84413 Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In the binary case you construct $x$ such that the $i$-th digit of $x$ is $0$ if the $i$-th digit of $f(i)$ is $1$ and vice-versa.